# Detection of charged particle in optical fiber cable

Tags: particle-physics, photons, experimental-physics, particle-detectors, optical-materials

There is a charged particle source and a light source attached to optical fiber cable which is attached to a light detector.

Is it possible to detect the passage of a charge particle through the cable due to change in the light (from the light source) that is received by the light detector? If yes, how does the detection/signal depends on particle energy and light wavelength ?

Google search gave me papers that are related to light induced in optical fiber by a charged particle e.g. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/732/1/012005/pdf.
Also, I tried looking here on Stack but could not find anything similar.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, charged particles going through a transparent medium with velocity higher than the velocity of light in the medium generate [Cerenkov  radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation) which is the [method used to detect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_detector) neutrinos,by neutrino  interactions in many large scale experiments giving rise to fast charged particles.

Now a fiber is transparent to light and if a fast  electron goes through there will be radiation, but if there is light going already through the fiber there will be superposition and a need to unravel the signal from the steady state.

The paper you quote is not talking of Cerenkov light, but of an effect due to the dipoles interaction with the charged particle, for very thin fibers.It sounds interesting and it seems to be designed for accelerator beams control. Try the [CERN 
 document server](http://cdsweb.cern.ch/) to see whether this research is pursued.